# How to generate the whole database script in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I want to take the whole database. Where do I find the database file?

And is there a way to write the whole database with all data to a text file (like the one in SQL Server)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Q#1: I would guess that it's somewhere on your MySQL server?
Q#2: Yes, this is possible. You have to establish a connection via Server Administration. There you can clone any table or the entire database.

[This tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20101119071045/http://database.blogs.webucator.com/2010/11/05/creating-database-backups-in-mysql-workbench/) might be useful.

**EDIT**

Since the provided link is no longer active, here's a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190083/how-to-take-mysql-database-backup-using-mysql-workbench) outlining the process of creating a DB backup in Workbench.

Comment: yeees this solve the problem ,thank you so much.

thank you every one for the help

Comment: somehow workbench 5.2 ce crashed when i try to backup my old database that is located on remote server 5.0.48; but old gui tools work successfully locally, through remote access.

Comment: The link in this answer is no longer active.

Comment: @Jason Thank you for pointing this out; I've provided an alternative link to a SO answer.

Answer (score 110):

### How to generate SQL scripts for your database in Workbench

1. In *Workbench Central* (the default "Home" tab) connect to your MySQL instance, opening  a *SQL Editor* tab.
2. Click on the *SQL Editor* tab and select your database from the *SCHEMAS* list in the *Object Browser* on the left.
3. From the menu select `Database > Reverse Engineer` and follow the prompts. The wizard will lead you through connecting to your instance, selecting your database, and choosing the types of objects you want to reverse engineer. 
   When you're all done, you will have at least one new tab called *MySQL* Model. You may also have a tab called *EER Diagram* which is cool but not relevant here.
4. Click in the *MySQL Model* tab
5. Select `Database > Forward Engineer`
6. Follow the prompts. Many options present themselves, including *Generate INSERT Scripts for Tables* which allows you to script out the data contained within your tables (perfect for lookup tables).
7. Soon you will see the generated script in front of you. At this point you can `Copy to Clipboard` or `Save to Text File`.

The wizard will take you further, but if you just want the script you can stop here.

A word of caution: the scripts are generated with `CREATE` commands. If you want `ALTER` you'll have to (as far as I can tell) manually change the CREATEs to ALTERs.

This is guaranteed to work, I just did it tonight.

Comment: This just gives me the create table not the inserts too.

Comment: There is a checkbox in the 'forward engineer' that says 'generate insert statements'

Comment: Thank you, that work for me. It is strange that option "Forward Engineer" does not exist until I performed "Reverse Engineer".

Comment: Thanks and this works for me except it doesn't generate the INSERT scripts even when I check that option.

Answer (score 14):

In MySQL Workbench 6, commands have been repositioned as the "Server Administration" tab is gone.

You now find the option "Data Export" under the "Management" section when you open a standard server connection.

Comment: And in MySQL Workbench 6.1 (Community) you will find it under the "Server" menu when you open a connection.

Comment: And if you need to export the INSERTS too, uncheck the option "Skip table data (no-data)"

Comment: There is now a drop down that allows you to pick "structure, data or both" once you are inside the "Data Export" section

Answer (score 11):

there is data export option in MySQL workbech

[image]

Answer (score 11):

I found this question by searching Google for "mysql workbench export database sql file". The answers here did not help me, but I eventually did find the answer, so I am posting it here for future generations to find:

**Answer**

In MySQLWorkbench 6.0, do the following:

1. Select the appropriate database under MySQL Connections
2. On the top-left hand side of screen, under the MANAGEMENT heading, select "Data Export".

Here is a screenshot for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

None of these worked for me. I'm using Mac OS 10.10.5 and Workbench 6.3. What worked for me is **Database->Migration Wizard...** Flow the steps very carefully

Answer (score 2):

Try the export function of [phpMyAdmin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin).

I think there is also a possibility to copy the database files from one server to another, but I do not have a server available at the moment so I can't test it.

Comment: i am not using phpmyadmin , in fact i am using asp.net with MySQL, and i am using MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE .

so is there any way to take the DB script using MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE??? and do you know if this application save database files in some where in the local Machine ???

Comment: While not what the OP asked for, I would second this as a preferred way of making a db dump over using Workbench. Workbench fails where PhpMyAdmin excels: InnoDB tables with foreign keys. Workbench's dumps will need to be manually modified before being imported. PhpMyAdmin's work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

In the top menu of MySQL Workbench click on database and then on forward engineer. In the options menu with which you will be presented, make sure to have "generate insert statements for tables" set.

Answer (score 2):

Using Windows 10 and MySql Workbench 8.0

1. Go to **Server** tab
2. Go to **Database Export**

This opens up something like this

[image: MySQL Workbench]

3. Select the schema to export in the **Tables to export**
4. Click the button **Start Export**

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly the Data Export in the MySql Workbench is not just for data, in fact it is ideal for generating SQL scripts for the whole database (including views, stored procedures and functions) with just a few clicks. If you want just the scripts and no data simply select the "Skip table data" option. It can generate separate files or a self contained file. Here are more details about the feature: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-data-export.html

Answer (score 0):

in mysql workbench server>>>>>>export Data
then follow instructions it will generate insert statements for all tables data each table will has .sql file for all its contained data