# generating the entire script in mysql from tables using mysql workbench?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, reverse-engineering

So I created a few tables and populated them using a script. The only problem is, I closed my script and I can't seem to find it. Is there a way to reverse engineer the entire script? I was looking at this earlier : [How to take MySQL database backup using MySQL Workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190083/how-to-take-mysql-database-backup-using-mysql-workbench).  But it I can't seem to find the server administration tab in order to start. Where is its location or is there an easier way to accopmplish what I am doing?

Comment: Have you looked at [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html) for doing a *backup* with `create-options` enabled? The top portion of the backup file will have all the SQL to create your tables.  (Left menu -> Management -> Data Export)

Comment: First start your question with some informations like on what platform you work, which MySQL Workbench version you are using and the like. Also be precise when you say you created tables. There's more than one place in WB where you can create tables. Best is a screen shot to show us what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

The "Server Administration" tab (in Workbench 5.2) was removed when Workbench 6.0 received a completely new GUI. Most of the functionality was moved to the Management Navigator inside of Workbench.

The [Workbench Data Export and Import](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html) documentation refers to all of the different methods that data can be exported and/or imported in Workbench.