# MySQL Workbench Reverse Engineer vs Export Data

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to takedown a database, but I want to be able to restore it later if I need to. Looking at MySQL Workbench I can find "Reverse Engineer" and "Data Export" as tools for achieving this.

What are the differences between those two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse Engineer to generate the EER diagram (behind the scenes).
check this [link](https://database.guide/how-to-reverse-engineer-a-database-in-mysql-workbench/)

Export data for Backup issues check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190083/how-to-take-mysql-database-backup-using-mysql-workbench/36284791)