# MySQL workbench : How to export mysql database to .sql file?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, export, mysql-workbench

I need to export my database in mysql workbench to a file .sql.

What to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate the whole database script in MySQL Workbench?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930733/how-to-generate-the-whole-database-script-in-mysql-workbench)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

try this and select export to self constrained file .sql along with the path.

[image]

Answer (score 64):

In MySql Workbench version 8.0 you can just follow the next steps

1. Go to **Server** tab
2. Go to **Database Export**

This opens up something like this

[image: MySQL Workbench]

3. Select the schema to export in the **Tables to export**
4. Click on **Export to Self-Contained file**
5. Check if **Advanced Options...** are exactly as you want the export
6. Click the button **Start Export**